# Concatenate multiple files skipping first line

Tags: bash

Let's assume three files f1,f2,f3 each containing:

```
header
line1
line2
```

Now I would like to concatenate all files beginning with "f" but skip the first line in each file - the final result should be:

```
line1
line2
line1
line2
line1
line2
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do it this way:

```
awk FNR!=1 f* > result
```

Answer (score 3):

With gnu coreutils:

```
tail -n+2 f*
```

Otherwise:

```
for f in f*; do tail -n+2 "$f"; done
```

or, if no filename contains a newline character

```
ls f* | xargs -I{} tail -n+2 {}
```

All of the above assume that there are no directories whose names start with `f`. Otherwise, again assuming no filename contains a newline character, you could use:

```
ls -p f* | grep -v / | xargs -I{} tail -n+2 {}
```

Or you could just redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` to ignore the error messages from `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `sed`:

`ls f* | xargs -I{} sed 1d {}`

Answer (score -1):

```
find f* -type f -exec tail -n +2 {} \; -exec printf "\n" \; > result
```

Potential empty lines in result can be taken of by:

```
grep -v '^$' result > result2
```

Comment: Did you try the last line? You'll find that it simply empties `result`, regardless of contents. Also, this is simpler: `grep . result > result.new`

Comment: It works fine once you change it from `result > result` to `result > result2`. :) The version I referred to was the unedited one, which, I repeat, will empty the file because you can't use a file as input and redirected output in the same bash command.

Comment: with `s/Linux/bash/`, I'd guess because `bash` has lots of corner cases. But it's the answering, not the asking, which needs to deal with them. :) (Btw, it wasn't me who down-voted.)